# Renewed load of AdMob in ListView

Tags: android, listview, admob

I have AdMob's in ListView, everything works fine, but...

Let assume the AdMob is at position 0, entirely at the top, then I am scrolling the list, so I don't see my AdMob. 
When I am returning to the top of my list, the AdMob is always again loaded.

How can I "hold" my AdMob to avoid renewed load of AdMob in my ListView?
Do I need AdListener?

Thanks!

Update:
I am adding AdMob in Java Class, something like this:

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    if (isItemAnAd(position)) {
        if (rowView instanceof AdView) {
            return rowView;
        } else {
            Activity activity = (Activity) context;
            adView = new AdView(activity, AdSize.BANNER,
                    AD_UNIT_ID_LISTVIEW_MAIN);
            adView.setLayoutParams(params);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            rowView = adView;
            return adView;
        }
    } else {

    ...Standard View...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to put your ad into the ListView. Instead put your ad immediately below the ListView.

Comment: I added my AdMob to ListView as in upper code. What do you mean with: "Don't try to put your ad into the ListView. Instead put your ad immediately below the ListView"?

Comment: Do not make your AdView one of the rows of your ListView. Instead make the AdView a separate view immediately below your ListView. That way you don't need to worry about reloading, what is getting displayed etc. Each object can handles its own responsibilities much more cleanly.